# It seems like url is not matching django

Tags: python, django

I have tried several options and help but the url is not matching. Here is my code

In `index.py`which just picks a random verse to display on my homepage

```
def index(request):
    rand = random.randint(1, len(Verse.objects.all()))
    context = {
        'verse': Verse.objects.get(id = rand)
    }
    return render (request, 'verse/index.html', context)
```

In `views.py`

```
def study(request, ref):
    context = {
        'verse': Verse.objects.get(reference = ref)
    }
    return render (request, 'verse/study.html', context)
```

`reference` is one of the field of my `Verse` model. The aim is to use the `ref` argument in the `urls.py` so that different pages could be generated by just appending the verse to the end of the link

In `urls.py`

```
url(
    regex=r'^study/(?P<ref>)/$',
    view = study,
    name = 'study'
),
```

In my `index.html`

```
<a href="{% url 'bible:study' ref %}"> Study</a>
```

I try to highlight on the link but this is what it generates

```
localhost:8000/bible/study//
```

instead of for example:

```
localhost:8000/bible/study/genesis/
```

Comment: Is `ref` defined in your template?

Comment: Where does `ref` come from in your *index.html* template?

Comment: show your index view (which renders `index.html`)

Comment: @morpheus `ref` is the argument from the `study` view

Comment: Please show the `view` which render `index.html`. Your `study` view renders `study.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing `ref` parameter to your `template` hence showing empty. According to the django documentation, undefined variables are treated as empty string by default. Read [**this**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables).

Modify your `index` view as,

```
def index(request):
    rand = random.randint(1, len(Verse.objects.all()))
    verse = Verse.objects.get(id = rand)
    context = {
        'verse': verse,
        'ref': verse.reference
    }
    return render (request, 'verse/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
context = {
        'verse': Verse.objects.get(reference = ref)
    }
```

in this 'verse' is the variable name for the html template and `Verse.objects.get(reference = ref)` is the value that Django replaces the 'verse' variable in the html during the webpage rendering.

It's showing `localhost:8000/bible/study//` becauseyou haven't defined any value for `'ref'` variable in your context.

Replace the 'ref' in your html with 'verse':

```
<a href="`{% url 'bible:study' verse %}`"> Study</a>
```

Comment: That context is being used for a completely different template (*verse/study.html*)

Comment: @mevius Yes, it is meant to link like an hyperlink from `index.html` to the webpage  for `verse/study.html`. So

Comment: @Tushortz , my comment wasn't directed at you. Please edit your question with the info 3 people have now asked you to provide.